# How to develop asp.net mobile application?

Tags: asp.net, mobile

how to develop asp.net mobile application? what steps I have to be follow from the beginning.  Is there any template provided by Microsoft for visual studio 2008 ? I want to develop this using c# + asp.net in mobile environment.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look [Mobile Web App toolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WebAppToolkitMobile). If you use MVC you can make 1 project. I recommend you don´t use mobile controls, they are deprecated.

Comment: Thanks I am going to download

Comment: Oh, i tried to install the toolkit. its almost done , also I can view the template,but i am  going to use template it is not working. showing some project file can not be loaded. what should do. i follow the instructions. but fail

Comment: look requisites, i remember you need vs 2008 and MVC. This is a great example for developing mobile web app using asp.net

Comment: but it is not installing properly. what have to do?